# how to add regex search values to variable list in Ansible?

Tags: regex, ansible

My requirement is to read tnsnames.ora file and get its' schema names to a variable list. Also need them add to the template.

Im able to match required schema names from tnsnames.ora file ([Matching](https://regex101.com/r/qlK5YL/1)). but in ansible, im not sure how to store all matching word in variable list. Appreciate your help to find a resolution.

```
- name: Lookup "{{ ansible_env.TNS_ADMIN }}/tnsnames.ora"
  slurp:
    src: "{{ ansible_env.TNS_ADMIN}}/tnsnames.ora"
  register: contents

- set_fact: matches="{{ contents['content'] | b64decode|regex_search(reg_pattern) |list|join("")}}"

- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ matches }}"
```

Below is regex pattern, which help me to get only the schema names.

```
reg_pattern: '^([^#()\W ][a-zA-Z.]*(?:[.][a-zA-Z]*\s?=)?)((\d*[a-zA-Z]*|(\0*)))'
```

Below is my tnsnames.ora file.

```
abcdsvsurv = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 30)
                        (DELAY = 5)
                )
        )
)

abcdsvsg = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

abcdsvser = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

abcdsvmtech = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

abcdsvyaan = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

abcdsvmrs = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

fltsurv03 = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 30)
                        (DELAY = 5)
                )
        )
)

fltsurvsg03 = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

fltsurvser03 = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

fltsurvmtech03 = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

fltsurvyaan03 = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)

fltsurv03surv = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 30)
                        (DELAY = 5)
                )
        )
)

fltsurvmrs03 = ( DESCRIPTION =
        (FAILOVER = ON)
        (ENABLE=BROKEN)
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.43.165)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = survdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE =
                        (TYPE = SELECT)
                        (METHOD = BASIC)
                        (RETRIES = 20)
                        (DELAY = 2)
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this task:

```
- set_fact:
    matches: "{{ contents['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall(reg_pattern, multiline=True) }}"
```

with that regexp:

```
reg_pattern: '^([^#()\W ][0-9a-zA-Z.]*(?:[.][a-zA-Z]*\s?=)?)'
```

Comment: Thanks @JGK, It is working. Can i know the mean of using '\\1'

Comment: `'\\1'` is a shortcut for `multiline=True` so you can write `regex_findall(reg_pattern, multiline=True)`

Comment: I think @JGK is wrong here. When you are doing `regex_replace` the `\\1` is a reference to the first matched parentheses. With `regex_findall` I don't think you can use it. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions

Comment: @JeroenVermeulen-MageHost you are right. This was for an older version of ansible, I can't remember which one. I corrected the answer.